# Success message after submiting the values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to display the success message in the label after submitting the values to the database. But its not display. I am new for this field. Please help me to do this..

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Insert Code is here
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>UpdateStatus('Record Added Successfully,'Green');</script>", false);
    }
    catch 
    {

    }
}

 UpdateStatus(Message) {
        var statusMsg = document.getElementById('lbl_status');
        statusMsg.innerHTML = Message;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a full postback that is not related whatsoever to javascript and all you need to do is change the label's text. I've got no idea what you are trying to do with the `RegisterStartupScript` call, but that's not how it is supposed to work. Simply set the label's text as below...

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Insert Code is here
        lbl_status.Text = "Record Added Successfully";
        lbl_status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
    catch 
    {
        lbl_status.Text = "Error";
        lbl_status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Just make sure your label is a server control with the `runat=server` attribute set

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
```

In codebehind

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Insert Code is here
        lblMessage.text ="Message Here";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
    catch 
    {
        lblMessage.text ="Message Here";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

But if you want a messagebox it is like this

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Insert Code is here
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "Message Here", false);
        }
        catch 
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "Message Here", false);
        }
    }
```

Then the messagebox will show.